# Testing Sagas in Rebus

Tags: unit-testing, rebus, saga

I'm tryng to read suggestion in [this blog post](http://mookid.dk/oncode/archives/3043) for testing some sagas behaviour. 
The problem starts as soon as I try to use `FakeBus`, since it should be in `Rebus.Testing` namespace but it seems disappered.

Where is the error? Lately a lot of things changed in Rebus, this is one of those changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, as you've correctly discovered, there's no `FakeBus` in [Rebus 2](http://mookid.dk/oncode/archives/3903) yet.

And as you might have found out as well, there is no `SagaFixture` either.

The reason is that I have found that using Rebus with an in-memory transport for testing has been sufficient for my needs so far, although I have had to do my saga testing at a fairly high level.

At this point though, so many people have asked for `SagaFixture` and `FakeBus` that I have now decided to put them back.

Expect them to be in Rebus 0.99.39 on of the following days (possibly tomorrow).